# PHP - assignment by reference with null coalescing operator

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment, php-7, null-coalescing-operator

I tried to create a variable that contains the reference to another variable if defined, or an other value:

```php
$arr = &$original ?? [];
```

In this example, everything is okay when `$original` is already defined. When it isn't, the **null coalescing operator** seems to be skipped as `$arr` contains `NULL` and not the *default* empty array.

Using a ternary operator would cause a parse error:

```php
$arr = isset($original) ? &$original : [];
```

The only way to achieve this would be with a `if` statement which is a longer syntax:

```
if (isset($original)) {
    $arr = &$original;
} else {
    $arr = [];
}
```

- Would there be a shorter way to achieve this ?
- Why does the null coalescing operator can't help here ? Should it ?

**EDIT:**
It appears that the assignment by reference will create the variable if it does not exists:

```php
$b = &$a ?? [];
var_dump($a); // without the previous line, triggers a "Notice: Undefined variable: a in ..."
```

But still, `$a` is `null`, and `$b` should contain an empty array.

Comment: Strange approach, if something defined - set reference, else set empty array. Maybe you should set `$original` to empty array if it is not set and just use `&$original` always?

Comment: @u_mulder I did not want to set the `$original` var if it wasn't already (it was a `$_SESSION` key in my case), but maybe I should always set it. Actually I did not need to do that and changed my code but I don't understand why the operator failed

Comment: Multiple solutions have been provided in a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724598/php-foreach-lose-reference-with-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Nice catch, @NeonDevil

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this as

```
$arr = isset($original) ? $arr = &$original :  [];
```

Comment: First solution does not work (array to string conversion), but the second one works well

Comment: You should get rid of the 1st solution, it still does not work as it is too limited. Just keep the 2nd one

Comment: @AymDev 1st solution removed.