# PHP - foreach lose reference with null coalescing operator

Tags: php, reference, null-coalescing-operator

Q1:
I think the `??` will do nothing when:

```php
$a = [1, 2];
foreach ($a ?? [] as &$v) {
    $v++;
}
var_dump($a);
```

But why?

```php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Q2:
This is more strange:

```php
foreach ($a = [1, 2] as &$v) {
    $v++;
}
var_dump($a);
// output
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

My thinking:
I think the expressions are not referencable, but `foreach` catch the error or somehow and then make a copy.
References that work:

```php
$a = 1;
$c = &$a;
```

Do not work:

```php
$a = 1;
$c = &($a);
$c = &($a ?? []);
$c = &($a + 1);
```

Dos `??` make a copy? I just don't want to wrap the `foreach` with a `if (isset($a))` if `$a` is null and `foreach` will fail.

Comment: because `$a` isn't empty o.O what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: dose `??` make a copy? I just dont want to wrap the `foreach` with a `if (isset($a))`  if `$a` is null and `foreach` will fail

Comment: Nope, it checks if the variable is empty, if so, use the value you set (in your case, and empty array, which won't loop) - read more [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)

Comment: Yes, it returns a copy of `$a` and `foreach` loops that copy not `$a`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver in what way? o.O to my understanding, it returns $a or [] (if $a doesn't exist/empty) - it's just a shorthand ternary if the value set = checked value

Comment: @treyake Correct but it returns a copy of `$a` not a reference to it.  Just like if you did `$b = $a;` and then `foreach $b` it won't change `$a`.

Comment: @treyBake It returns __not__ `$a`, but __value__ which is stored in `$a`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver isn't that a result, not a copy of?

Comment: @u_mulder yeah, I just mean, it's not a copy of $a, it's the value of

Comment: I would have thought the for the loop is the result of the expression `$a ?? []`

Comment: See this https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html

Comment: @treyBake https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php _Note that the assignment **copies** the original variable to the new one (assignment by value), so changes to one will not affect the other. This may also have relevance if you need to copy something like a large array inside a tight loop._

Comment: @AbraCadaver but it's a [comparison operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)? o.O

Comment: @treyBake other comparison operators return things, like `true` or `false` this one returns a copy of `$a` or an empty array.

Comment: My answer already answers your edit as `($a ?? [])` actually returns `[1, 2]` and you can only reference a variable, so things like `&($a ?? [])` don't work because that is an expression not a variable.

Comment: Did you give up?  You have lots of comments since your only comment and 3 answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** For your case, you could consider using the null coalesce operator in this manner:

```php
$a = $a ?? [];
foreach ($a as &$v) { ... }
```

Or, don't use references at all, by either using `array_map()` or by using  the keys to make modifications in the underlying array.

### Q1

```php
$a = [1, 2];
foreach ($a ?? [] as &$v) {
    $v++;
}
var_dump($a);
```

The coalesce operator uses a copy of the original array, and then applies the right hand operand if `null`. Therefore, the iteration happens over a copy of the original array.

You could compare this to the following:

```php
$a = [1, 2];
$x = $a ?? [];
$x[1] = 4;
var_dump($a); // [1, 2]
```

#### Code Insight

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $a, !1 = $v
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   8     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, <array>
   9     1        COALESCE                                         ~3      !0
         2        QM_ASSIGN                                        ~3      <array>
         3      > FE_RESET_RW                                      $4      ~3, ->8
... rest of looping code
```

The first operand of `FE_RESET_RW` is the hash variable that will be iterated over, and you can see that it's `~3` instead of `!0` (`$a` in your code), which is what you expected to happen.

### Q2

```php
foreach ($a = [1, 2] as &$v) {
    $v++;
}
```

What happens here is that the return value of the assignment `$a = [1, 2]` gets used as the array to iterate over.

You can compare this behaviour to something like this:

```
$x = $a = [1, 2];
$x[0] = 4; // modify in-place
var_dump($a); // [1, 2]
```

#### Code Insight

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $a, !1 = $v
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                           $2      !0, <array>
         1      > FE_RESET_RW                                      $3      $2, ->6
... rest of looping code
```

Again, `$2` is the first operand of `FE_RESET_RW`, which is the assignment result, and so iteration will not happen against `!0` (`$a` in your code).

Comment: Q2: if `$a` is copied, then there are two `[1, 2]`, the copied/second one is named as `$a`, and the first is still unnamed and cannot be used, is it a memory waste? The first one can only destroy when exceeding the variable scope.

Comment: You could do `$a = $a ?? []`, and then `foreach ($a as ...)` to avoid wrapping with `isset()`; I've updated my answer

Comment: I think PHP should at least throw a warning if you are using null coalesce operator and the reference at same foreach. I've faced an issue for cause of this on yesterday. Thanks for your explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expanded array syntax to get the index, and then use that to dereference the original array value:

```
$a = [1, 2];
foreach ($a ?? [] as $i => $v) {
    ++$a[$i];
}
var_dump($a);
```

But note this is likely useless anyway, because if `$a` isn't set (so that the `??` qualifies) then the loop will make zero iterations and `$a` will still be unset for the `var_dump()`. (Unless that's what you need, I suppose...)

Comment: This is neat, always use index, otherwise `&$v` must be manually `unset($v)` following `foreach` to avoid unexpectedly modified later.

Answer (score 0):

> I just dont want to wrap the `foreach` with a `if (isset($a))` if `$a` is null and `foreach` will fail.

This is unavoidable if you haven't initialized variables to the correct type, but here's some trickery in a utility function using pass by reference, return by reference and a default value:

```
function &test(&$array=[]) {
    return $array;
}

$a = [1, 2];

foreach (test($a) as &$v) {
    $v++;
}
```

Doesn't generate errors if `$a` is not set and doesn't loop, however in the above it yields:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  &int(3)
}
```

In PHP arrays are assigned by value (assignment copies), so that if `$a !== null` then `$a ?? []` returns the value of `$a` or `[1, 2]`.  So `$a` is not modified by the reference to the values of this value using `&$v`.

Objects are assigned by reference so a reference is returned in this case and the original object is modified, unless `$a` is not set.  Then you will obviously get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: a

```
$a = (object)[1, 2];

foreach ($a ?? [] as &$v) {
    $v++;
}
var_dump($a);
```

This yields:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["0"]=>
  int(2)
  ["1"]=>
  &int(3)
}
```

From [Assignment by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference):

> Assignment by reference is also supported, using the `"$var = &$othervar;`" syntax. Assignment by reference means that both **variables** end up pointing at the same data, and nothing is copied anywhere.

In these cases, they are all expressions and cannot be referenced:

```
$c = &($a);
$c = &($a ?? []);
$c = &($a + 1);
```

If this is just an exercise that's fine, but if you are trying to solve a specific problem then you need to outline that broader problem.